# Google Sign-In showing Error 400: invalid_request Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain in Javascript

Tags: javascript, localhost, google-signin

The HTML code looks like this with  tag and  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="791276359692-0c2cpgs7dds6ffivpdjlrlhfgr82aao1.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <title>Journal App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: I am using Pure Javascript to use Google Sign-In, but the below image shows when I try to sign in]

I am using VS Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the Authorized Javascript Origins, URI's value should not be its IP address but "localhost:(port if any)".